# Add values with same date in a List ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am new to asp.net core. I have a list object which contains lot of data with fields date, order value, delivery cost, order status etc.

What I want to do is add all the order values which fall under same date.
can anybody help me out with this?

For example the data on the list is as follows:-

```
Order Date                 Order Value
--------------------------------------
24/09/2020                     £3
24/09/2020                     £5
26/09/2020                     £7
26/09/2020                     £2
26/09/2020                     £3
```

I want to display the date without repetition and add the values with same date and store it in the list

Comment: 1) where is the list code that you already are using to do this? do you get any error when you try to use it.

Comment: no i dont get any error and i am able to display the data from the database properly. here is the list code     var res = await dbContext.Order.OrderBy(x => x.OrderModified).ToListAsync();

Comment: @user14375406 <code>fOoreach (var item in res)
                {
                    if (item.Id == defaultId)
                    {                        
                        StoreDetails.Add(item);
                    }
                }   the store details is a list which contains all the items

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an `Order` class like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

you can first [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) the order date, and then take the [`Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netcore-3.1) of the orders in each group. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var orders = new List<Order>
    {
        new Order { DateCreated = DateTime.Parse("24/09/2020"), Value = 3 },
        new Order { DateCreated = DateTime.Parse("24/09/2020"), Value = 5 },
        new Order { DateCreated = DateTime.Parse("26/09/2020"), Value = 7 },
        new Order { DateCreated = DateTime.Parse("26/09/2020"), Value = 2 },
        new Order { DateCreated = DateTime.Parse("26/09/2020"), Value = 3 },
    };

    var orderTotals = orders
        .GroupBy(x => x.DateCreated)
        .Select(group => new 
        { 
            DateCreated = group.Key, 
            Total = group.Select(order => order.Value).Sum() 
        });

    foreach (var item in orderTotals)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.DateCreated} - {item.Total}");
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
24/09/2020 00:00:00 - 8
26/09/2020 00:00:00 - 12
```

#### Update from comments

Assuming you're using Entity Framework, the process for doing the above is pretty much the same. To make things a bit easier in terms of returning the data to a caller, let's define another class:

```
public class OrderTotal
{
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

It means you can do something like this in your page:

```
public class OrderModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _dbContext;

    public OrderModel(YourDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<OrderTotal> OrderTotals { get; set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    // Read the orders from the database, instead of from a list.
    var orderTotals = _dbContext.Orders
        .GroupBy(x => x.DateCreated)
        // Notice we're using OrderTotal now, rather than an
        // anonymous type. This is to make it easier to
        // use the data outside of this method.
        .Select(group => new OrderTotal
        { 
            DateCreated = group.Key, 
            Total = group.Select(order => order.Value).Sum() 
        });

    OrderTotals = await orderTotals.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}
```

Then for the view portion:

```
@page
@model IEnumerable<YourProject.Models.OrderTotal>

<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Order Date</th>
        <th>Order Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach (var order in Model)
      {
        <tr>
          <td>@order.DateCreated</td>
          <td>@order.Total</td>
        </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. Really appreciate it but again there is a problem. The dates and the values I will be getting from the database and not hardcoded so how to identify that it is of the same date e.g if the date is 24/09/2020 or 26/09/2020.

Comment: @user14375406 No problem. `GroupBy` groups things that are identical, so if 2 rows in your `Orders` table, or however you're storing them, have the same date, they will be grouped together. But this does assume you have stored the exact same date for each of the rows you want to group together.

Comment: @user14375406 I've added a simple example, which assumes you're using Entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot @John H for your answer. I am just a newbie so I apologise if I am irritating you people. I don't have much knowledge.  I am using api/controller so I don't have any idea whether I can return _dbContext.orders instead of returning page. The place where I am doing all this is derived from PageModel so can you please elaborate a little bit more. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @user14375406 I've added a much larger example, but that's all I can do at this point. You really need to work through some tutorials for both [Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/) and [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#prerequisites-1), if that's what you're using, because there are basics you're missing that mean it's almost impossible to help you beyond this point.

Comment: Thanks again for your efforts. I have tried what you said but it is giving me unhandled exception error. I am posting my entire code so that you get the idea of what I am doing. Also I am providing you the output which I am displaying in the view.

Comment: @Bhargav Rao why did you delete my post? What harm did I do to you

Comment: Thanks again for your efforts. I have tried what you said but it is giving me unhandled exception error. I am posting my entire code so that you get the idea of what I am doing. Also I am providing you the output which I am displaying in the view.

Comment: `public async Task OnGet() { try { StoreOrderDetails = new List<Store_Order>();

            var res = await UOW.CurrentContext.StoreOrder.OrderBy(x => x.OrderModified).ToListAsync();

            foreach (var item in res)
            {
                StoreOrderDetails.Add(item);
            }

            totalCount = StoreOrderDetails.Count();
            StoreId = defaultStoreId;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return Page();
    }`

Comment: 01/09/2020 05:30:16 3 2.00 0 New
01/09/2020 10:39:43 3 1.00 0 New
01/09/2020 10:50:22 3 2.00 0 New
02/09/2020 05:07:28 3 7.00 0 New
03/09/2020 04:31:12 3 10.00 0 PaymentComplete
07/09/2020 22:23:56 3 1.00 0 New
07/09/2020 22:27:11 3 2.00 0 New
07/09/2020 22:29:22 3 2.00 0 New
10/09/2020 08:44:54 3 5.00 0 New

Comment: @user14375406 Your `catch` block is empty, so you're hiding the exception. Change it to `catch (Exception ex)` and please examine it with your debugger. This isn't even the same question any more. Please have a read through the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to understand how stackoverflow works.